# Error when invoking chaincode in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I have made my custom chaincode "mycc.js" It is successfully installed on peer. But when i **Instantiate** this chaincode using

`peer chaincode instantiate -l node -n mycc -v v0 -C mychannel -c '{"args":["init","A","100","B","100"]}' -o locahost:7050`

command. I got error this error
[image: Error: Error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to locahost:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you check you core peer address?

Comment: Seems like you forgot sth to 'adjust' in docker context. Can you check related docker logs?

Comment: @kajuken My peer logs says failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: handler not found for chaincode mycc:v0

Comment: @AlexanderYammine How can i check my core peer address? In docker-compose.yml file my core peer suppose to run on port 7052

Answer (score 1):

It's localhost, not locahost, you are missing "l"